# Why not working the preg replce in iframe?

Tags: php, iframe, preg-replace

I would like to embed youtube links, but I also would like to embed the links from `['url']`.
I dosen't get any wrong php messange.
My php code is:

```
$search = '#<iframe(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*<\/iframe>#x';
 $replace = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
 $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

And the iframe:

```
echo ' <iframe class="video" allowfullscreen style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;" width="658px" height="569"  frameborder="0" src="'.$row['url'].$text.'"></iframe>' ;
```

I would like to fix this becouse now if you give a youtube link the output looks like this:

```
<iframe class="video" allowfullscreen="" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;" width="658px" height="569" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dh-0jH4Rb7Y"></iframe>
```

Comment: you want to get youtube links from database and put them in an iframe ?

Comment: Yes, but I also would like to, embed the [url] field gived link.

Comment: Becouse any link possible on there.

Comment: So if the user give different url which not contain youtube url,  also should be embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use:

```
$fullUrl = //put here anything you want, be it result from MySQL or $_POST
echo ' <iframe class="video" allowfullscreen style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;" width="658px" height="569"  frameborder="0" src="'.$fullUrl.'"></iframe>' ;
```

and decide what should `$fullUrl` be ahead of echoing? For preg_replace to work you can't echo, you need to assign it to variable first. And why you want to preg_replace something that you assign with variable by yourself? Waste of memory and time.

Comment: You mean I must use two iframe in one page becouse of youtube?
I would like to solve this with on iframe is this possible.

Comment: So for example, I would like to embed an html file  if it was a link.
But if you just was a youtube link, it would be great if it could be embedded.